# php jquery ajax search does not show live results

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, live, mustache

I am making a live search page and I think there is something wrong with the jquery part of the code. And maybe even only with the "mustache" part. Because When I check my browser's "network" page I can see it is sending to the .php page. But it does not show anything.

my code:

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Search</title>
</head>
<body>
<p>Search: <input type="text" id="query"></p>
<p>
    <input type="radio" name="match_type" value="0"> Begins with |
    <input type="radio" name="match_type" value="1"> Ends with |
    <input type="radio" name="match_type" value="2" checked> Contains
</p>

<hr/>

<ul id="results"></ul>


<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mustache.js/0.8.1/mustache.min.js"></script>
<script type="mustache/x-tmpl" id="names_tmpl">
{{#names}}
<li>{{name}}</li>
{{/names}}
{{^names}}
<li><em>No matches found</em></li>
{{/names}}
</script>

<script>
$("#query").keyup(function(){
    var q = $(this).val();
    var match_type = $("input[type=radio]:checked").val();
    var data = {query: q, match_type: match_type};

    if(q.length == 0 || q ==  " ") {
        return false;
    }

    $.ajax({
        url: "instant-search.php",
        data: data,
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(res) {
            var tmpl = $("#names_tmpl").html();
            var html = Mustache.to_html(tmpl, res);

            $("#results").html(html);
        }
    });
});

$("input[type=radio]").change(function(){
    $("#query").trigger("keyup");
});

$("#query").focus();
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

instant-search.php (but I guess there's nothing wrong with that. Didn't use PDO here but mysql just to check it out on my localhost)

```
<?php

class MyDb {
private $db;

public function __construct($host, $username, $password, $dbName) {
    $this->db = mysql_connect($host, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($dbName);
}

public function __destruct() {
    mysql_close($this->db);
}

public function select($query) {
    return $this->toArray(mysql_query($query));
}

private function toArray($res) {
    $arr = array();

    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
        $cols = array();

        foreach($row as $key => $val) {
            if (is_string($key)) {
                $cols[$key] = $val;
            }
        }
        array_push($arr, $cols);
    }
    return $arr;
}
}

class MatchType {
const BEGINS_WITH = 0;
const ENDS_WITH = 1;
const CONTAINS = 2
}




function processRequest($query, $matchType) {
$db = new MyDb("localhost", "root", "", "search");

$like = "'%{$query}%'";
switch ($matchType) {
    case MatchType::BEGINS_WITH:
        $like = "'{$query}%'";
    break;

    case MatchType::ENDS_WITH:
        $like = "'%{$query}'";
    break;
}

$selectQuery = "SELECT name FROM names WHERE name LIKE {$like} ORDER BY name ASC";
$results = $db->select($selectQuery);

header("content-type: application/json");
echo json_encode(array("names" => $results));
}

$query = $_POST["query"];
$matchType = isset($_POST["match_type"]) ? $_POST["match_type"] : MatchType::CONTAINS;

processRequest($query, $matchType);
```